# XML parsing error remedy

Tags: xml, parsing

during parsing an XML file, i am facing parsing error like `[Fatal Error] :293:24: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.` My XML sample contains some characters like **xc3**, which is a single character (I mean by pressing delete button once **xc3** character deletes at a time. (I tried to paste this character here but this editor is showing other character).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<issue-info>
<issue-meta>
<date>January 24, 2013</date>
<from>Chris Burton, John Wiley &amp; Sons, Ltd.</from>
<journal>Greenhouse Gases: Science and Technology</journal>
<typesetter>Anju Upadhaya</typesetter>
<volume>3</volume>
<issue>1</issue>
<printer>Markono,</printer>
<cover-date>February 2013</cover-date>
<online-issn>2152-3878</online-issn>
<print-issn>2152-3878</print-issn>
<total-pages>FM &ndash; 4; TEXT &ndash; 95; EM &ndash; 1: TOTAL = 100</total-pages>
<spl-instruction></spl-instruction>
</issue-meta>
<issue-item>
<seq>1</seq>
<ed-ref>OFC</ed-ref>
<aid></aid>
<author></author>
<description>Update from GHG 2_1 cover</description>
<start-page>1</start-page>
<end-page>1</end-page>
<artty></artty>
<category>OFC (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>2</seq>
<ed-ref>IFC</ed-ref>
<aid></aid>
<author>49379Ůpdf</author>
<description>New GHG colour ADVERT</description>
<start-page>2</start-page>
<end-page>2</end-page>
<artty></artty>
<category>IFC (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>3</seq>
<ed-ref>FM1</ed-ref>
<aid></aid>
<author></author>
<description>Table of Contents</description>
<start-page>1</start-page>
<end-page>1</end-page>
<artty></artty>
<category>TOC (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>4</seq>
<ed-ref>FM2</ed-ref>
<aid></aid>
<author></author>
<description>Editorial Board</description>
<start-page>2</start-page>
<end-page>2</end-page>
<artty></artty>
<category>Editorial Board (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>5</seq>
<ed-ref>FM3</ed-ref>
<aid></aid>
<author></author>
<description>Aims and Scope</description>
<start-page>3</start-page>
<end-page>3</end-page>
<artty></artty>
<category>Aims and Scope (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>6</seq>
<ed-ref>FM4</ed-ref>
<aid></aid>
<author></author>
<description>Information Page</description>
<start-page>4</start-page>
<end-page>4</end-page>
<artty></artty>
<category>Information Page (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>7</seq>
<ed-ref></ed-ref>
<aid>GHG1333</aid>
<author>PROD ED</author>
<description></description>
<start-page>1</start-page>
<end-page>2</end-page>
<artty>ED</artty>
<category>Editorial (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>8</seq>
<ed-ref></ed-ref>
<aid>GHG1334</aid>
<author>PROD ED</author>
<description></description>
<start-page>3</start-page>
<end-page>4</end-page>
<artty>XX</artty>
<category>60 Second Interview (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>9</seq>
<ed-ref></ed-ref>
<aid>GHG1335</aid>
<author></author>
<description></description>
<start-page>5</start-page>
<end-page>7</end-page>
<artty>XX</artty>
<category>Feature (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>10</seq>
<ed-ref>GHG-12-0029.R2</ed-ref>
<aid>GHG1313</aid>
<author>PAN, CLODIC, TOUBASSY</author>
<description></description>
<start-page>8</start-page>
<end-page>20</end-page>
<artty>XX</artty>
<category>In the Field (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online>03 Jan 2013</pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>11</seq>
<ed-ref>GHG-12-0023.R1</ed-ref>
<aid>GHG1298</aid>
<author>Peterson, O'Byrne, Endres, Peterson</author>
<description></description>
<start-page>21</start-page>
<end-page>29</end-page>
<artty>XX</artty>
<category>Spotlight (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online>14 Sep 2012</pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>12</seq>
<ed-ref>GHG-12-0033.R2</ed-ref>
<aid>GHG1321</aid>
<author>Begag, Krutka, Dong, Mihalcik, Rhine, Gould, Baldic, Nahass</author>
<description></description>
<start-page>30</start-page>
<end-page>39</end-page>
<artty>XX</artty>
<category>Spotlight (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>13</seq>
<ed-ref>GHG-12-0036.R1</ed-ref>
<aid>GHG1331</aid>
<author>Cunningham, Lauchnor, Eldring, Esposito, Mitchell, Gerlach, Phillips, Ebigbo, Spangler</author>
<description></description>
<start-page>40</start-page>
<end-page>49</end-page>
<artty>XX</artty>
<category>Spotlight (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>14</seq>
<ed-ref>GHG-12-0034.R1</ed-ref>
<aid>GHG1328</aid>
<author>Elliot, Buscheck, Celia</author>
<description></description>
<start-page>50</start-page>
<end-page>65</end-page>
<artty>XX</artty>
<category>Modeling and Analysis (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>15</seq>
<ed-ref>GHG-12-0021.R1</ed-ref>
<aid>GHG1318</aid>
<author>Mazzoldi, Picard, Sriram, Oldenburg</author>
<description></description>
<start-page>66</start-page>
<end-page>83</end-page>
<artty>XX</artty>
<category>Modeling and Analysis (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online>03 Jan 2013</pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>16</seq>
<ed-ref>GHG-12-0031.R1</ed-ref>
<aid>GHG1308</aid>
<author>Eccles, Pratson</author>
<description></description>
<start-page>84</start-page>
<end-page>95</end-page>
<artty>XX</artty>
<category>Modeling and Analysis (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online>26 Oct 2012</pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>17</seq>
<ed-ref>EM1</ed-ref>
<aid></aid>
<author>Join the SCI</author>
<description>NEW COLOUR ADVERT</description>
<start-page></start-page>
<end-page></end-page>
<artty></artty>
<category>Society Ad (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>18</seq>
<ed-ref>IBC</ed-ref>
<aid></aid>
<author>ONLINE OPEN</author>
<description>COLOUR ADVERT</description>
<start-page>1</start-page>
<end-page>1</end-page>
<artty></artty>
<category>IBC (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
<issue-item>
<seq>19</seq>
<ed-ref>OBC</ed-ref>
<aid></aid>
<author>CCUS</author>
<description>NEW COLOUR ADVERT</description>
<start-page>2</start-page>
<end-page>2</end-page>
<artty></artty>
<category>OBC (GHG)</category>
<toc-category></toc-category>
<reprint></reprint>
<color>N</color>
<color-charge>0</color-charge>
<pub-online></pub-online>
</issue-item>
</issue-info>
```

My Java code for parsing is here below.

```
       DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);
        docBuilderFactory.setCoalescing(false);
        docBuilderFactory.setXIncludeAware(false);
        docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        docBuilderFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        docBuilderFactory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);

        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(rtfXmlIS);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

How to get rid of such kind of error (`[Fatal Error] :16:45: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.`, `[Fatal Error] :14:24: The entity "ndash" was referenced, but not declared.`)?

Comment: Edit your post and include the first 20-30 lines of the input XML

Comment: Hi @Jim, added the sample. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's two different errors.

The first is because the input is not UTF-8.  You will need to decode the input correctly before passing it to the parser.

The second is probably because the input is XHTML and not XML.  If you want to use an XML parser with this input and resolve entities like `&ndash;` you will need to provide a DTD that defines it and any others contained in the input.

Comment: Hi @Jim, Will you please elaborate that how to parse XML in UTF-8 format? Or how to skip parser from reading that character. Please provide a pseudo code.

Comment: Edit your post to include a sample of the input XML.

Comment: Hi @Jim, added the sample. Please have a look

Comment: @Saikat, the first line of your XML asserts that the file is encoded in UTF-8, but it isn't. It's encoded in iso-8859-1 or something similar. It's important that the encoding asserted in the XML declaration should match the actual encoding of the file.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay : Thanks a lot for your response. But XML file I am getting as an input is populating from client side. So I want to handle it from my side. Is there any possibility to convert that format for my sake or is there any possibility to skip the BOM characters? Eagerly waiting for your response sir. As I am working with XML files for the first time.

Comment: Well, it's always best to fix encoding errors as close to their origin as you can. But if you can't, then ad-hoc repair is usually possible; for example by "fixing up" the XML declaration before you pass the file to an XML parser.